# Login to Spring Boot with AngularJS $http.post

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring-security, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application and want to log into it via my angularJS service. I did log in via postman which saves the cookie in my browser, but I want to log in again using my service. Due to my cookie I can call any controllers in my spring boot app ( they all require authentication). But all login requests fail with error 'Unauthorised'. Full browser console output -
POST http://localhost:3344/bl/login 401 (Unauthorized)

Security config for spring ( I extend WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter):

```
@Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication()
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
                .usersByUsernameQuery(USERS_BY_USERNAME_QUERY)
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(AUTHORITIES_BY_USERNAME_QUERY);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                    .exceptionHandling()
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                    .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/").authenticated()
                    .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/bl/login")
                    .usernameParameter("user")
                    .passwordParameter("pass")
                    .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
                    .failureHandler(new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler())
                    .and()
                .logout()
                    .logoutUrl("/logout")
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true);
    }
```

My Angular service is pretty simple:

```
loginModule.factory('loginService', function($http) {
  return {
    login: function(username, password) {
      $http.post('/bl/login', {user: 'admin', pass: 'admin'}).then(
        function(response) {
          window.alert('success')
        },
        function(response){
          window.alert('fail')
        });
    }
  };
});
```

I also created a controller as a 'mock' login service to test my angular code:

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/bl/login2", produces="application/json")
  JSONResponse login(@RequestBody LoginCreds credentials) {

    return new JSONResponse("logged in " + credentials.getUser());
  }
```

This controller works and I can see that my login and password are passed correctly and I get the response back to my angular service.
LoginCreds contains 2 strings 'user' and 'pass'. 
JSONResponse contains a single string.

Comment: maybe this can help https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/12/the-login-page-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-ii

Answer (score 3):

Solved it, the problem was that in my spring configuration I have 'formLogin()' that means i have to change the content type header in my request from angular service to 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'.
And serialize the data accordingly.
[This link explains it with examples.](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2615-posting-form-data-with-http-in-angularjs.htm)

My end result looks like:

```
     var req = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'bl/login',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
        data: $.param({ user: username, pass: password }),
      };

      $http(req).then(
        function(response) {
          window.alert('success')
        },
        function(response){
          window.alert('fail')
        });
      }
```

Since angular serializes data to JSON by default we need to use $.param() function for serialization.

Comment: Thanks! That helped me a lot.